# Outputs in console with WriteConsoleOutputA

Tags: c++, winapi, console

Hi I'm trying to make an output with `WriteConsoleOutputA`.
I have this code:

```
CHAR_INFO letterA;
letterA.Char.AsciiChar = 'A';

letterA.Attributes =
    FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY |
    BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_INTENSITY;
    //Set up the positions:
    COORD charBufSize = { 1, 1};
    COORD characterPos = { 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT writeArea = { 0,0,0,0 };

    //Write the character
    WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, &letterA, charBufSize, characterPos, &writeArea);
```

So at this point it writes a red `A` with a yellow background, but for example, if I want the `A` appear in the coordinates (5,5) it doesn't print it even if I change `SMALL_RECT` to `{0, 0, 10, 10}`.

Or if I want to write another `A` right side to the first one with this:

```
WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, &letterA, charBufSize, characterPos, &writeArea);
WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, &letterA, charBufSize, { 0, 1 }, &writeArea);
```

I´m beginning with this graphical console mode, it would be very helpful if someone could tell me how to print that character in the coordinate that I want.

I have tried to change it , changing the coordinates something like this:

```
COORD charBufSize = { 5, 10};
COORD characterPos = { 3, 2 };
SMALL_RECT writeArea = { 0,0,5,10 };
```

but it prints weird characters and other colours in all the buffer 5*10.

Thanks

César.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`WriteConsoleOutput(..)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404(v=vs.85).aspx) is a complex function which needs to be handled carefully.

The `dwBufferSize` parameter (= your `charBufSize`) is nothing more than a size specification of the `lpBuffer` parameter (= your `letterA`). The only difference instead of simply telling that `letterA` has a size of `1` is that by splitting it into two axis you are able specify the width and height of a text block with `letterA` characters in it. But remember that the size of `letterA` has to be `charBufSize.X * charBufSize.Y`. Otherwise `WriteConsoleOutput` will do weird stuff since it uses uninitialized memory.

The `dwBufferCoord` parameter (= your `characterPos`) defines the location within `letterA` from where to read the characters to be written to the console. So it simply defines an index offset. In your example this should always be `{ 0, 0 }` (which is equal to `letterA[0]`) since `letterA` is only a single character.

The `lpWriteRegion` parameter (= your `writeArea`) does all the magic. It specifies the position, width and height of the area to be written by the call. The data to be written is definedby the previous parameters.

So to write a character to a specific location `x, y` do the following:

```
COORD charBufSize = {1, 1};
COORD characterPos = {0, 0};
SMALL_RECT writeArea = {x, y, x, y};

WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, &letterA, charBufSize, characterPos, &writeArea);
```

For a little better understanding use the following example and play a little with the values of `charBufSize`, `characterPos` and `writeArea`:

```
int i;
CHAR_INFO charInfo[10 * 10];

/* play with these values */
COORD charBufSize = {10, 10};   /* do not exceed x*y=100 !!! */
COORD characterPos = {5, 0};    /* must be within 0 and x*y=100 */
SMALL_RECT writeArea = {2, 2, 12, 12};


for (i = 0; i < (10 * 10); i++)
{
    charInfo[i].Char.AsciiChar = 'A' + (i % 26);
    charInfo[i].Attributes = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_INTENSITY;
}

WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, charInfo, charBufSize, characterPos, &writeArea);
```

Here is a screenshot of the parameters in the example above showing the console and the variables. I hope this makes it a bit more clear.

[image: Parameter example]

Comment: Hi Lukas, thank you very much, this was very helpful, it helped me to understand a little bit more about that function.

Comment: Really thankful Lukas for this example with screenshot. I read the msdn document which has more word but it didn't help me as your example.